# Percentage in hctreemap2 of Highcharter using tooltip?

Tags: r, highcharts, tooltip, percentage, treemap

I made a treemap with Highcharter. As the map is interactive I want it to show both the total quantity and the percentage that each group represents of the total. I have the following 2 codes that I made based on other questions here but both ways it shows the percentage at 0.00%.
How can I add percentage information to the highcarter treemap tooltip?

```
#Way 1
hctreemap2(data =Objeto,
           group_vars = c("objeto_contratar"),
           size_var = "total",
           color_var = "total",
           layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
           levelIsConstant = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[2],
               maxColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[7]) %>%
               hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "Objeto: {point.name} <br>
                            Contratos: {point.value:,.0f} <br>
                            Porcentaje: {point.percentage:.2f} %")  %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)

#Way 2
hctreemap2(data =Objeto,
           group_vars = c("objeto_contratar"),
           size_var = "total",
           color_var = "total",
           layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
           levelIsConstant = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[2],
               maxColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[7]) %>%
  hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function(){
                                return  '</b>'  + this.point.name + ': <br> Contratos: ' +this.point.value+' <br> Porcentage: '+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.percentage)+'%'
  }"),useHTML = FALSE)  %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)

Could someone tell me how do I get it to display both data (the amount and percentage it represents) on the same graph when I hover over it?
```

Comment: Could you provide your data so I can run your chart? I can see you are already using pointFormat and formatter and you are using point.percentage in both of them - what is the exact problem then? What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone helped me. This is what he did and it works. I hope this helps someone else.

```
hctreemap2(data =Objeto,
               group_vars = c("objeto_contratar"),
               size_var = "total",
               color_var = "total",
               layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
               levelIsConstant = FALSE) %>% 
      hc_colorAxis(minColor = pal_azul(7)[1],
                   maxColor = pal_azul(7)[7]) %>% 
      hc_tooltip(formatter = JS('function () {
                            var total = 0;
                            for (var i = 0; i < this.series.data.length; i++)
                            {
                            if (this.series.data[i].node.children.length == 0)
                            total+=this.series.data[i].node.val;
                            }
                            var value;
                            if (this.point.node.children.length == 0)
                            {
                            value = this.point.options.value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            value = this.point.node.childrenTotal;
                            }
                            var porcentage = (value / total) *100;
                            return  "</b>"  + this.point.name + ": <br> Contratos: " +this.point.value+" <br> Porcentage: "+Highcharts.numberFormat(porcentage)+"%"
                            }'),useHTML = FALSE)  %>% 
      hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```